# What's the best way to customize the css in Magento 2?

Tags: theme, css, luma-theme

I created my theme as Luma child but I cannot really understand what's the best way to customize the css. Until now I just wrote all of my styles in *_extend.less* file but it's a lot of stuff for just 1 file I think! So...

What's the best way and upgrade-proof to extend the Magento Luma theme?

- Should I use Magento UI Library?
- Should I write all my styles in *_extend.less* file?
- Should I overwrite *_theme.less* file and customize it?
- Should I mix all this up?

Where can I find a specific tutorial or course which clearly explain this? I tried to read the official doc but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

After you extend the theme, you also will extend different modules(for example Magento_Theme, Magento_Catalog, Magento_Checkout) and in that modules(let's say Catalog) you will have different folders: layout-where you will put xml files, templates-where you will put phtml files, and web-where you will have css/source/_extend.less and in there you will modify the css for the catalog page, because is the best solution to separate all css, also in web folder you have a js folder. I am also a beginner in Magento but that's how i learned.
So the best way is to have one _extend in any module you will extend to not have all css code from all store in one file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create page wise less like below

_header.less
_home.less
_footer.less

you can import this less in your _extend.less file line

@import 'theme/_header.less';
@import 'theme/_home.less';
@import 'theme/_footer.less';

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this article: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html